# Size of TTStyledText with floating image is being computed wrong

Tags: iphone, ios4, three20

I have a TTStyledText with a floating image. The problem that I am facing is that the height of the text incase there is a floating image larger than text, is being computed wrong. Instead of incorporating the size of the image + text accompanying the image, The implementation just returns size of text. This causes the image to be clipped.

Any one else has faced this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally solved this by defining a TTBoxStyle with minimum size. This way even if the image is clipped the minimum size ensures that some part of the image is displayed properly.